# How can you match words with more than one character?

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use a regular expression to match all words with more that one character, as opposed to words entirely made of the same char.

This should not match: ttttt, rrrrr, ggggggggggggg

This should match: rttttttt, word, wwwwwwwwwu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following expression will do the trick.

```
^(?<FIRST>[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*?(?!\k<FIRST>)[a-zA-Z]+$
```

- capture the first character into the group `FIRST`
- capture some more characters (lazily to avoid backtracking)
- ensure that that the next character is different from `FIRST` using a negative lookahead assertion
- capture all (at least one due to the assertion) remaining characters

Note that is sufficient to look for a character that is different from the first one, because if no character is different from the first one, all characters are equal.

You can shorten the expression to the following.

```
^(\w)\w*?(?!\1)\w+$
```

This will match some more characters other than [a-zA-Z].

Answer (score 1):

I would add all unique words to a list and then used this regex

> \b(\w)\1+\b

to grab all one character words and get rid of them

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use a regular expression, but I believe it will do what you require:

```
public bool Match(string str)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
               || str.ToCharArray()
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Any( c => !c.Equals(str[0]) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following RE will do the opposite of what you're asking for: match where a word is composed of the same character.  It may still be useful to you though.

```
\b(\w)\1*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\w*?(\w)\1*(?:(?!\1)\w)\w*\b
```

or

```
\b(\w)(?!\1*\b)\w*\b
```

This assumes you're plucking the words out of some larger text; that's why it needs the word boundaries and the padding.  If you have a list of words and you're just trying to validate the ones that meet the criteria, a much simpler regex would probably do:

```
(.)(?:(?!\1).)
```

...because you already know each word contains only word characters.  On the other hand, depending on your definition of "word" you might need to replace `\w` in the first two regexes with something more specific, like `[A-Za-z]`.